# Backing up a self-hosted Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress instance that runs on a VPS I own, so I have full (root) shell access.

Let's say I want to backup and restore my wordpress content so I can move it to another server.

What do I need to back up?

My guess is -

- Backing up the full wordpress directory (since it contains plugins, configs, etc..)
- Backing up the full mysql wordpress database

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the wp-admin site I recommend migrate with this plugin [wp-clone](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/), this is the one that I use. If you don't have then you do what you said:

1. Migrate the wp-content and the mysql database.
2. Install wordpress in the new server and change the wp-content and the new database with the old one.

Comment: Thanks! Just confirming - there's a lot of `wp-*` folders under the wordpress folder. Is it guaranteed that `wp-content/` is the only one that needs to be backed up? What about something like `wp-includes/` ?

Comment: Yes, those are defaults functions that bring Wordpress, the one that you change are only wp-config and wp-content basically. If you change another file like .htaccess you can verify it and add it to the new server.